# Having problems with unity: spacebar input don't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i was triyng to start programming a videogame for a University project. I started with player controls and i have problems with the spacebar input. It register the input only sometimes, i also used a ceck variable to see if it was a problem of the jumping code but i saw that unity dosen't register the input a lot of time.

```
public bool control;


forzaSalto = 300;

Rigidbody2D player;
float? asseY;
public bool saltando;

void Awake()
{
    player = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    player.Sleep();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if ((verticale != 0 || orizzontale != 0) && !accovacciato)
    {
        Vector3 movimento = new Vector3(orizzontale * velocita, verticale * velocita, 0.0f);
        transform.position = transform.position + movimento * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    Gira(orizzontale);

    if (transform.position.y <= asseY && saltando)
    {
        Atterraggio();
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")){
        control = !control;
    }

        



    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && !saltando)
    {
        asseY = transform.position.y;
        saltando = true;
        player.gravityScale = 1.5f;
        player.WakeUp();
        player.AddForce(new Vector3(transform.position.x + 7.5f, forzaSalto));
    }
}
```

I tried to adjust the jumping code but it still don't work and then i used a ceck variable to see that the problem is with unity not seeing my spacebar input. Also with the controller dosen't work. It register only sometimes the input. I'm using unity 2022

Comment: I missed a code section, really sorry. This functions is used to stop the player when the jump ends

`void Atterraggio()
{
    saltando = false;
    player.gravityScale = 0f;
    player.Sleep();
    asseY = null;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, ty all anyways. The problem whas in the input type: i used `Input.GetButtonDown()` and when i switched with `Input.GetButton()` it started working. I don't know why it wasn't working but now it register all the inputs. This was my first post, sry if i missed some code parts or if it wasn't clear.

Comment: My guess would be that ? `GetButtonDown()` set `control` to "false", when you hit spacebar and didn't reset when you released it, basically missing every second input. `GetButton()` registers on Press *and* Release, iirc, alternating the value of `control` the desired way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In `FixedUpdate()` all updates from the physics engine are processed. This happens only at regular (fixed) frame/time intervals. Since you don't use the phyics engine for movement, you don't need to uses `FixedUpdate()`.

Try `Update()` instead, since Unity might miss some inputs or process them too late with `FixedUpdate()`.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted .. it is at least one of the main issues here ... of course we have no insight in what is setting `saltando = false` or what `control` is used for ...and finally there is also a mixed usage of `transform.position` and `Rigidbody.AddForce` which can't be quite right ...

Comment: I moved the funcion inside 'Update()' it works better but still misses some inputs, i also changed the button with C but it still dont work, so i assume it's a code problem